# "teilweise" als Adjektiv und Verbalsubstantive

Tags: single-word-request

Kürzlich bin ich im Duden auf etwas Merkwürdiges gestoßen:

> **<mit Verbalsubstantiven auch attributiv>: die Polizei wertete die Aktion als teilweisen Erfolg**

Wieso ausgerechnet mit Verbalsubstantiven?

Eine Recherche bei [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/teilweise) ergibt, dass dies tatsächlich der Fall ist. Das bezweifle ich jedoch, da z.B das Wort *[partiell](https://www.dwds.de/wb/partiell)* ähnliche Ergebnisse hervorbringt.

Existiert in der Tat solch eine Regel oder ist dies ein Irrläufer?

Comment: Wenn du zwei Wörterbücher findest, die dir nicht recht geben, kannst du natürlich hier fragen. Und wir werden dir natürlich auch nicht recht geben. Kann natürlich auch sein, dass ich einfach deine Frage nicht verstanden habe...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ich erkläre mir das Duden-Beispiel so, dass 'teilweise' ursprünglich Adverb ist. Es kann als Adverb Verben bestimmen:

> ich hab das nur teilweise verstanden

oder Adjektive:

> das Haus ist erst teilweise fertig

oder andere Adverbien:

> die Aufgabe wurde teilweise falsch gelöst.

Man kann es aber nicht prädikativ einsetzen:

> *alle Sätze hier sind nur teilweise (statt etwa 'unvollständig')

und normalerweise auch nicht attributiv zu einem Nomen

> *ein teilweiser Baum (statt 'ein Gehölz, das man ebenso gut als Baum wie als Strauch bezeichnen könnte').

Das alles gilt in ähnlicher Weise auch für 'partiell' und, wenn mann so will, auch für das Wortbildungselement 'Teil-' ('Teilerfolg' geht, 'Teilbaum' geht nur fachsprachlich, 'Teilstrauch' geht überhaupt nicht).

Dennoch kann nach Duden ein attributiver Gebrauch vorkommen, wenn das dadurch bestimmte Nomen von einem Verb abgeleitet (ein Verbalsubstantiv) ist:

> ein teilweiser Erfolg

Das Duden-Beispiel ist nicht unmittelbar verständlich, da einem durchschnittlichen Deutschen weder bewusst noch für ihn transparent ist, dass 'Erfolg' von 'erfolgen' abgeleitet ist. Außerdem hat das Verb 'erfolgen' eine nur schwer fassbare Bedeutung. Anders jedoch bei

> ein teilweiser Missbrauch, ein teilweiser Gewinn, ein teilweises Beschäftigungsverbot, eine teilweise Übereinstimmung...

Hier versteht man, dass man etwas oder jemanden per Übergriff teilweise missbrauchen kann, dass man bei einem Kampf gleichzeitig sowohl gewinnen als auch verlieren kann, dass einer Schwangeren das Arbeiten teilweise verboten werden kann und sie damit bestimmte Tätigkeiten nicht ausführen darf, und dass Sachverhalte teilweise übereinstimmen und sich in anderen Punkten unterscheiden können. Die Überführung der (syntaktisch) adverbialen in eine (syntaktisch) attributive Verwendung beruht auf semantischer Analogie, bei der die Grammatik ein wenig strapaziert wird: Wenn ich sagen kann, dass zwei Texte teilweise übereinstimmen, warum soll ich dann nicht von 'teilweiser Übereinstimmung' reden können?

Es gibt wahrscheinlich viele Adverbien, die auf ähnliche Weise in andere syntaktische Kontexte verpflanzt werden. Ob sie da immer gut gedeihen, ist zumindest eine Geschmacksfrage:

> eine dermaßene Unverschämtheit, eine flugse Antwort, nebenbeies Radiohören, eine zeitweise Erschöpfung, ein deshalbiges Zuspätkommen, eine zweifelsohne Lüge

Das hört sich alles an wie die berühmte 'zue Tür', da liegt der Fall aber noch etwas anders. Für den Duden bestand das Problem, einerseits solche Kombinationen für unzulässig, andererseits jedoch erklären zu wollen, dass *teilweise* auch in sonst standardsprachlichem Kontext entgegen der Wortartzugehörigkeit dekliniert und attributiv verwendet werden kann. Die 'Regel': *nur vor Verbalsubstantiven* ist dafür ein Ansatzpunkt. Ob das durchgehalten wird, wäre dann an vielen einzelnen Adjektiven zu überprüfen. Ich bezweifle das, denn der Online-Duden ist z.B. im Punkt der Wortartbestimmung ziemlich unpräzise, vermutlich weil die Zielgruppe der Seite ein nicht linguistisch vorgebildetes Publikum ist. Was dort alles unter 'Adverb' läuft, wird heute in deutschen Grammatiken, auch in der Duden-Grammatik, viel stärker ausdifferenziert. Außerdem handelt es sich bei dieser Frage oft um Grenzfälle, bei denen eine Entscheidung 'geht' (standardsprachlich) oder 'geht standardsprachlich nicht' schwer zu treffen ist.

Answer (score 1):

Du kennst vielleicht den Spruch

> Ein bisschen schwanger gibt es nicht.

So etwas wie

> Petras teilweise Schwangerschaft

würde also keinen Sinn ergeben. Erfolg dagegen kann man auch nur zum Teil haben, daher wohl die Festlegung auf Verbalsubstantive. Eine explizite Regel hierzu ist mir allerdings nicht bekannt.